# Chart data does not link to interactive report page in APEX

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I am attempting to create a link in an APEX (Oracle) chart which will open an interactive report page by using the "Link Builder -Target" wizard.

Link Builder -Target Dialog][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl7k7.jpg)

Unfortunately the link is passing the column name (bob) rather than it's value:

https://xxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx:xxxx/ords/f?p=100:51:19910173095277::NO:RP,51:P51_TARGET_FIELD:#BOB#

If I substitute a value for #BOB#, the interactive page opens properly.

How do I get APEX to pass the column value rather than the column name to the linked page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Page Designer vs Legacy Component View](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/switching-page-designer-to-component-view.htm#HTMDB-GUID-B9787F85-4FEA-473A-9BBB-F53B1330BD09)

Apex 5.0 still using anychart charts, but using Page Designer the query of the chart is not validate. If you change to Legacy Component View you must see a error on save the chart with this query.

---

The selects in anychart charts need a query following these terms:

[image]

*BOB column is not valid to use on Link Builder Target

Try to put the value of the BOB column in the LINK column, like:

SELECT
bob AS LINK,

or use [APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_util.htm#AEAPI160), in this case it's not necessary to use Link Builder Target.
...

---

The query needs only three columns called LINK, LABEL and VALUE. Use alias to make this.

```
SELECT 
APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL
('f?p=&APP_ID.:14:&APP_SESSION.::::P14_RECIEVER,P14_VALUE:' || bob || ',' || quantity) AS LINK, 
month AS LABEL, 
quantity AS VALUE
FROM mytable
```

---

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550

Workspace: STACKQUESTIONS

User: test

Password: test

Issue page: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:10

Comment: > &BOB < or > &BOB. <. Please try &BOB. (
With dot in the end)

Comment: Neither &BOB or &BOB. worked. However, for what it's worth, "&BOB" was passed to the target page whereas "&BOB." was not.

Comment: I think it worked, but in this case the value of the BOB column is null. Check the html of the url now. And execute the select on "Commands SQL" check if the column is really null

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Check the html of the url now." Can you explain. The BOB column simply lists the months of the year (12 records) It contains no null values.

Comment: please try, only to test, change your select to something like this SELECT null LINK, '8' as BOB ... what happens? (Using &BOB., with dot).

Comment: I have done as you suggested, and changing BOB to '8' as BOB (Using &BOB., with dot) makes no difference.

Comment: I created two pages in you test environment "EC..." with the simplest of queries. The link worked as expected. I then created identical pages in my site, and they fail. Clearly, the issue is with the application instance. Do you have any idea what this may be?

Comment: Sorry, I really have no idea how to solve this problem. Maybe David Peake knows, I think he's the guy who works on building APEX.

Comment: I think I was able to replicate your issue on page 10 of the test application (link in response). The problem is related to what David Peake said about the type of chart (AnyChart x JET). It seems that in anychart charts custom columns are not accepted in the link configuration (in Link Builder Target). Try using the "LINK" column of your query in the "VALUE" field on "Link Builder Target". Your original select would look like: SELECT bob as LINK.

Comment: I placed "BOB" in the LINK column, and it was passed to the target page as you predicted. Unfortunately, the "VALUE" fields continue to fail to be passed. Is this what you also expected? Please forgive me my ignorance, but as a clarification of what you are saying, are you suggesting that I build the URL using the 'PREPARE_URL Function' and, place this URL in the LINK field?  If so, are you able to provide an example of what this might look like?

Comment: ok, look at the page 10 of this application, make login and check the query and how is the link builder target now.

Comment: Okay- This is great, but there is one more "slight twist" to the problem. Because this chart contains three series (years)  using the select statement "SELECT 
APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL
('f?p=&APP_ID.:51:&APP_SESSION.::::P51_TARGET_FIELD1,P51_TARGET_FIELD2,P51_TARGET_FIELD3,P51_TARGET_FIELD4:' || MONTH || ',' || VALUE1 || ',' || VALUE2 || ',' || VALUE3) AS LINK, 
month AS LABEL, 
VALUE1 AS VALUE1, VALUE2 AS VALUE2, VALUE3 AS VALUE3"

Comment: ( I have changed some of the column names for clarity, I am sorry if this is confusing.) Returns all three series values for the given month. I would like it to return only the value for the bar which was 'clicked'. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I do not know what type of chart you are using, but i refreshed the test application to use two series (you can do more). If you replicate the exact issue that you have is better. Anyway you can use CASE statement to make a link conditionaly:

Comment: That was it! I was building the chart from one query rather than three separate queries. After splitting out the series, everything worked perfectly. Thank you very much for helping me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is BOB a chart column?
If not in the Link Builder, use the selector on 'Value' to select the corresponding column from the chart, such as #NAME#.

Regards,
David

Comment: "Bob" is a column in the query from which the chart is created. "#BOB# is visible in the 'Value' selector, and this is how I configured the "Link Builder -Target" wizard originally. Following is the select statement from that query:SELECT null LINK, BOB, "2015-2016","2016-2017","2017-2018". I realize the column names are somewhat unorthodox. Is this something in this statement that that could be causing the issue?

Comment: What version of APEX are you running?
APEX 5.1 includes Oracle JET Charts instead of AnyChart.
Based on the query it seems you are using AnyChart.
Can you upgrade your chart to Oracle JET? 
FYI - apex.oracle.com is running APEX 5.1.4

Comment: I am running 5.0.1. Do you think this may be causing the issues that I am experiencing?